# Can't call matplotlib attributes v3.2.2

Tags: matplotlib

Whenever I try to run the following code I get an error message

```
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import _pickle as pickle
import numpy as np


print(matplotlib.version)
```

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'version'

I get the same error if i try this: `matplotlib.style.use('bmh')`

I'm using PyCharm

Comment: You have likely named a file matplotlib.py somewhere.

Comment: @JodyKlymak closest to that name that i found were "test_matplotlib.py" and "matplotlibtools.py"

Answer (score 0):

The errors are stating those attributes do not exist. It is not a problem of the installation.

To get the version:

```
print(matplotlib.__version__)
```

Regarding the style:

You do not "apply" that in matplotlib. You may want to use the module pyplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("bmh")
```